# Ajax/jQuery live search is duplicating the output results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm currently working on `Ajax` and `jQuery` live search which finds a results in a `JSON` file. Script is working fine, but the is only one problem - it's duplicating the result data.

**EXAMPLE**:

[image: Results]

**MARKUP**:

```
<div class="row">
  <h3>Live Search Results</h3>
  <div id="update-results">
  <p>event_name | club_name | memberid</p>
    <ul id="update">
      <!-- <li><a href="#"></a></li> -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var $update = $('#update');
    $update.empty();

    $.get("getEventsWithVideos.php?text=" + searchField, function(data) {
      var vals = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        if($.isArray(vals['Event'])) {
          $.each(vals['Event'], function(k,v){
            $update.append("<li value='"+v['id']+"'><a href='#'>" + v['event_name'] + "</a></li>");
          });
        } else { 
            $update.append("<li value='"+vals['Event']['id']+"'><a href='#'>" + vals['Event']['event_name'] + "</a></li>");
        }

    });
});
```

I've tried to debug and stop the error, but it was unsuccessful. Can anyone help me please with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the empty() *inside* the response handler:

```
$.get("getEventsWithVideos.php?text=" + searchField, function(data) {
     $update.empty();
```

basically you are clearing the list on every keystroke (rapid), then requesting the data, then (sometime  later) *appending* the results that come back (which could be multiple results depending on the timing).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't reproduce your error but I suspect that you have problem with multiple request to server and adding them all instead of last one. Probably adding below code will fix your problem

```
$update.empty();
```

Anyway I suggest you to use 2 more functions: throtlle and `debounce` from underscore to prevent too much request on every `keyup`.

Also you could try Rx.js witch give following example (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS):

```
var $input = $('#input'),
    $results = $('#results');

/* Only get the value from each key up */
var keyups = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($input, 'keyup')
  .map(function (e) {
    return e.target.value;
  })
  .filter(function (text) {
    return text.length > 2;
  });

/* Now debounce the input for 500ms */
var debounced = keyups
  .debounce(500 /* ms */);

/* Now get only distinct values, so we eliminate the arrows and other control characters */
var distinct = debounced
  .distinctUntilChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm already found a simple solution which I was looking for.

Comment: No problem. I just want You to think about too much redundant requests :)

Comment: No worries, I've already sorted it with just simply limiting the output results in SQL statement :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line **$update.empty();** of your code to **$update.find('li').remove();** and put it  inside the response handler.

This removes all the previous data before you append the new values. Hopefully it might work.

Comment: `empty` does the same thing.

Comment: The only correct part of your answer is the edit you updated *from the correct answers*. That is the `empty` needs to be inside the response handler. :)